# how to iterate values in php from arraylist to be display inside the html table

Tags: mysql, html, arraylist, pdo

I am able to get the values from my Database table in the array form. 
But i do not know how to print those values in my  `<table><tr><td>// values of subjectId comes here  </td> 
<td>//values of subject Name comes here</td></tr></table>`. I want to iterate all the fields values one by one in my  tag.

In Array i am getting values like this:

```
FIctionNon FIctionArray ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subject_id] => 1 [subject_name] => FIction [creater_id] => 1 [created_date] => 2012-10-07 16:49:12 [update_id] => 1 [updated_date] => 2012-10-07 16:49:12 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [subject_id] => 2 [subject_name] => Non FIction [creater_id] => 1 [created_date] => 2012-10-07 16:49:12 [update_id] => 1 [updated_date] => 2012-10-07 16:49:12 ) )
```

And my code for getting output is as follows:

---

```
     $con = new connection(); 
     $info = new Subdetails_setup($con); 
     $results = $info->getSubjectInfo(); 
     print_r($results);
```

And my Method look like this:

```
 function getSubjectInfo()
 { 
    $sub_info = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjectdetails");
    $sub_info->execute();

    $results = $sub_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($results as $key)
        { 
           echo $key->subject_name; 
        }
    // Return the result array
        return $results;
   }
```

My table is. "Subjectdetails"

```
        subject_id int(3) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
        subject_name varchar(150) NO NULL
        creater_id int(5) NO NULL
        created_date datetime NO NULL
        update_id int(5) NO NULL
        updated_date datetime NO NULL
```

.
Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

To split apart your arrayed values, couldn't you use the explode function? I'm unfamiliar with it so I wouldn't be able to help with that. But, could you go about collecting your values, and echoing them a different way? Like shown below

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from subjectdetails ORDER BY `subject_id` DESC ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $subjectid = $row['subject_id'];
   $subjectname = $row['subject_name'];
   (The rest of your values here)
   echo "
<table><tr><td>$subjectid</td> <td>$subjectname</td></tr></table>
";
}
```

I did not test that, but it should work.

Comment: thank youu. This is not fine way for me to display values. I already written Select query in my classes.And returning the arraylist to the index.php. How to display values from arraylist in my index.php.

Comment: I think both would work, they're just different methods. I'm not familiar with the method you're using using though, so I'm unable to help. Sorry. If you'd try my method, it might work though.

Comment: But, I think you are looking for the explode(); function. Here is a link that will help you with that. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: i am looking for php5 based answer. Answer which you have provided is in very simple way.This type of solution i know. I am trying to learn MVC in PHP.